# Webkit <button onclick> does not fire in certain situations

Tags: javascript, button, webkit, onclick

I noticed that **in Webkit** the `<button>` element does not fire the `onclick` event when the mouse is moved from/to child elements of the button during the click. With other words: when the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events do not happen on the same element - even if both are children of the button.

The same happens when clicking/releasing on/out of the *pixels* of the button *text*.

To clarify I made a **testcase**: http://jsfiddle.net/gx9B3/

It works fine in FireFox. Fails in Chrome 15 and QtWebkit 4.7.1

Is there a way around this? I need a solution **specifically for Webkit** because my project is targeted to this browser only.

## Solution

I could solve this problem based on the method suggested by **Jan Kuča** (the solution I accepted). Some additional tweaks were necessary, especially introducing a timer to avoid double clicks. Have a look at my fully working solution at JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mwFQq/

Comment: You're lucky to have a project targeted only for WebKit.

Comment: wow, that was weird. Never noticed that before

Comment: This is a bug in WebKit, which was apparently recently fixed in Blink (for Chrome), though I'm not seeing it yet: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39620

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set up a `mousedown` listener on `document.body` (to fix the problem on the whole page). You would check if the `mousedown` event originated from an `HTMLButtonElement` (or from any of its child elements) and if it did, you set up a `mouseup` listener (on the button so it does not have to bubble too much) that will check the `target` property of the `mouseup` event. If it is contained in the button and is different from the `target` of the `mousedown` event, you fire a `click` event like this:

```
var e = document.createEvent('Events');
e.initEvent('click', true, true);
button.dispatchEvent(e);
```

(Do this only for WebKit-based browsers so that you don't get multiple click events in other browsers. Or you could call the `preventDefault` method of the `mousedown` event as it should also prevent firing the `click` event.)

Comment: Very good idea. I tried to implement your suggestion [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PvFKv/1/). It works, but `preventDefault()` seems to be ignored (tried in `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `click`) and so the `click` is fired twice in those cases where the workaround is not needed. Any idea why that is?

Comment: You can also try returning false in the mousedown listener. If this does not work, you are probably stuck with browser detection such as `/webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)`.

Comment: Have a look at [my new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvFKv/1/) I had already posted in my previous comment. The problem is not browser detection, but instead avoid double clicks in WebKit when the browser itself emits `click` because `mouseup` and `mousedown` were at the same pixel position. `return false;` doesn't help either. But anyway I wonder why `preventDefault()` doesn't work after all..!?

Comment: Now that I think about that, you would not only prevent firing of the `click` event but also of the `mouseup` event. Therefore, I can't think of a better solution than browser detection right now.

Comment: Hey, I see you did not implement my logic correctly. `clickBtn && clickBtn === btn` is not the right thing to check. I would check for `clickBtn && btn && mousedown_event.target !== mouseup_event.target`

Comment: Ok, although I thought about that you didn't mention it in your answer... :) Anyway, I [tried it](http://jsfiddle.net/PvFKv/2/) and it works for the image-inside-button scenario. But for the plain text button the `target` is always the button itself (just try it yourself). And from what I can tell there is no way to check that in the mouse event. Perhaps I'll have to use a timer or something like that. But shouldn't `preventDefault` at lease prevent `onclick` when used inside the `click`event handler?

Comment: I think it should be possible to check this even for text-only buttons. This is, however, not suited for a comment. I'm going to write a little blog post about this. I thought of a solution using client rectangles and computed style of the button.

Comment: Wrapping a `<span>` around the text helps, but the problem remains for the very first click when I try to add the `span` in `mousedown`, of course.

Comment: I accepted your solution as it is the basis of my complete solution. See edited question for details. Thanks.

Comment: Still happening today with QtWebKit 5.3. Workaround did work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this CSS style:

```
button * {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Child elements will then ignore mouse events and the click will come from the button element itself. Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/Tetaxa/gx9B3/2/

Comment: Oh QtWebKit you mean. Haven't got that myself so I can't test it.

Comment: Try Chrome 15 (my version is 15.0.874.106 and should be the most current one).

Comment: Sorry, this *does* help for the button with a image inside, but *not* for a plain text button.

Comment: You're right, I must've moved the pointer to the side and still been inside the text's bounding box. This should probably be reported as a bug in WebKit.

Comment: Found an already existing bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39620

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve it by pure CSS trick. Just place pseudo element over `<button>` to cover text:

```
button {
    position:relative;
    }
button:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    content:'';
    }
```