# C# WebKit Browser Click event

Tags: c#, events, browser, webkit, click

I'm trying to do click event in one of buttons in page which I opened with WebKitBrowser (I'm using c# 2010 EE). Well, found nothing with google... I even heard it's not possible with WebKitBrowser. So my question is: anyone solved this problem? Or maybe You can suggest what can I use instead WebKitBrowser and default WebBrowser?

Comment: Just googled and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982213/webkit-button-onclick-does-not-fire-in-certain-situations). Not sure if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I'm looking for function which will simulate click on button, or run it's function.